# Difference between two date and times

Tags: java, android, datetime, date

I need to find difference between to times. This is my code

```
LocalDateTime ltdNow = LocalDateTime.now();

LocalDateTime ltdThen = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-07-30T08:00:00");

Duration duration = Duration.between(ltdNow, ltdThen);
System.out.println(duration.toDays + " Days and " + duration.toHours);
```

However i need it in this format `23 Days and 17 Hours` but it gives me large number like `19804` as the hour.
How can i convert it to this format?

Comment: I see you’re in Sweden. In Sweden summer time (DST) ends in the night between October 24 and 25, so from 2020-10-24T12:00:00 to 2020-10-25T12:00:00 will be 25 hours, not 24. Do you then want `1 days and 1 hours` or just `1 day and 0 hours`?

Comment: You need parentheses for toHours() and toDays().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [LocalDateTime#until](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-)

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime ltdThen = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-07-30T08:00:00");
        LocalDateTime ltdNow = LocalDateTime.now();

        // ###########With Java-8###########
        long days = ltdNow.until(ltdThen, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        long hours = ltdNow.until(ltdThen, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
        System.out.println(days + " days and " + (hours % 24) + " hours.");

        // ###########Java-9 onwards###########
        Duration duration = Duration.between(ltdNow, ltdThen);
        System.out.println(duration.toDaysPart() + " days and " + duration.toHoursPart() + " hours.");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
22 days and 15 hours.
22 days and 15 hours.
```

**Note:** `Duration#toDaysPart` and `Duration#toHoursPart` was introduced with Java-9.

Answer (score 3):

`toHours()` does exactly what it says: The number of hours between the two dates.

Try `toHoursPart()`, I think that's what you're looking for:

```
System.out.println(duration.toDays() + " Days and " + duration.toHoursPart());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Stockholm");
    
    ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
    ZonedDateTime zdtThen = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-10-26T08:00:00").atZone(zone);
    
    long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(zdtNow, zdtThen);
    ZonedDateTime afterDays = zdtNow.plusDays(days);
    long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(afterDays, zdtThen);
    
    System.out.println("" + days + " days and " + hours + " hours");
```

Output when running today just before 18:00 Swedish time:

> 110 days and 14 hours

Messages:

- Don’t trust the `Duration` class to calculate days. It calculates a day as always 24 hours. Because of summer time (DST) and other anomalies a day is occasionally longer or shorter in real life. The calculation I am doing above crosses the transition from summer time to standard time in Sweden and correctly calculates 25th October as 25 hours, not 24.
- Don’t do your own division or multiplication to convert between days and hours. One, it doesn’t give you a reliable result for the reason just stated. Two, if this was what you wanted, you should still leave the conversion to library classes, for example `Duration`.

Comment: Precise answer ;)

Comment: I do not think if it makes any difference whether we use `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` in this case because the given date-time string does not have time-zone information. When it comes to the diff between date-times in different TZs, time-zone does matter but when it comes to the difference between two date-times in the same time-zone, it doesn't matter which TZ we use. Am I missing anything? **Note:** I feel proud to say that the credit of most of the things about modern date-time API I have learnt, goes to you and [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It will very seldom make a difference as long as you are sure that both start and end times are in the same time zone. The corner case is when counting *hours* until a time in the night where the clocks change. In this case there are 4 hours from 01:00 to 04:00 in that night, where `LocalDateTime` will obviously only count 3. Which result you want, you will have to decide for yourself, of course.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Period  :

```
LocalDateTime ltdNow = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime ltdThen = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-07-30T08:00:00");
Period p = Period.between(ltdThen , ltdNow );
long p2 = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(ltdThen , ltdNow );
System.out.println("You are " + p.getYears() + " years, " + p.getMonths() +
                   " months, and " + p.getDays() +
                   " days old. (" + p2 + " days total)");
```